# Input redirection in gdb (MinGW)

Tags: gdb, mingw

I'm trying to get gdb to run programs with input redirection to stdin. For example, without gdb I would run a program like this:

```
prog < input.txt
```

Now in gdb, the usual way to do this is `run < input.txt`. However, it doesn't work for me and when doing this nothing gets redirected into stdin.

I'm using Windows with MinGW. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 15):

As far back as the late '90s, broken command line redirection was a [known and assumed limitation](https://sourceware.org/ml/cygwin/1999-04/msg00355.html).  My suspicion is that it remains that way, since the `mingw32` port of `gdb` still gleefully passes on verbatim all `run` arguments (including redirects) to the debugee.

Several possible workarounds:

1. if you have the option to alter the command line interface, then implement `bbadour`'s suggestion
2. otherwise, if you can easily suspend the process before the point you want to debug at, invoke the debugee (with redirection) from a shell and attach to it while it is already running
3. otherwise, if you have symbols for the debugee (`gcc -g`) or you know the address of `main()` (`gcc -Wl,-Map,mapfile`) and can set a breakpoint there, proceed in the following manner (tested with `mingw gdb 6.8.0`):

   ```
   # gdb debugee.exe
   (gdb) b main
   (gdb) run non-redirect-arguments-if-any
   (gdb) p dup2(open("/tmp/input.txt", 0), 0) 
   (gdb) c
   ```

Comment: I'm running into the same problem as the OP. However, I am unable to get the 3rd solution to work for me. This is on `gdb 7.5.50`. How does the 2nd solution work? How do you ensure that when the debuggee is started, it doesn't just run to completion before you have a chance to attach gdb to it?

Comment: @greatwolf it depends on your program specifics. Say, in C/C++ it could be achieved by raising a signal - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326414/set-breakpoint-in-c-or-c-code-programmatically-for-gdb-on-linux

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue here, and I just got into the habit of adding a command-line argument to allow grabbing input from a file.

e.g. Parsing a "-i ifile" argument using argc and argv to get input from ifile instead of stdin and parsing a "-o ofile" to write output to ofile instead of stdout.

Then I just use those arguments instead of redirects.

The tools that come with MinGW often are not the latest versions and often have features omitted. ::shrug::

Answer (score 0):

Input redirection is supported starting with GDB 8.0.  From the NEWS file:

- Native debugging on MS-Windows supports command-line redirection

  Command-line arguments used for starting programs on MS-Windows 
  can now include redirection symbols supported by native Windows 
  shells, such as '<', '>', '>>', '2>&1', etc.  This affects GDB
  commands such as "run", "start", and "set args", as well as the 
  corresponding MI features.