# Set breakpoint in C or C++ code programmatically for gdb on Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, gdb

**How can I set a breakpoint in C or C++ code programatically that will work for gdb on Linux?**

*I.e.:*

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    /* set breakpoint here! */
    int a = 3;
    a++;  /*  In gdb> print a;  expect result to be 3 */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Very much a side note (sorry to nitpick), but if you're worried about portability then you're probably also worried about correctness - hence `int main` rather than `void main`.

Comment: @Stuart - Fixed.  Should have done that a while ago.

Comment: @J.Polfer: The `return 0` is not necessary, though, and is just noise!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit the `return 0;` is 100% necessary. Besides the warning your compiler *should* throw at you, this can corrupt the stack on older/embedded systems, and as such should ALWAYS be done out of habit and correctness. Forget a return in other places in your code and you're guaranteed to pay for it on modern desktop systems, too.

Comment: [Is there a portable equivalent to DebugBreak()/__debugbreak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173618/is-there-a-portable-equivalent-to-debugbreak-debugbreak)

Comment: @Jimmio92 No, `main` is special in all versions of C++ and also in C since C99. Reaching the final `}` of `main` without returning is equivalent to `return 0;` so the compiler should **not** warn, and it cannot corrupt anything. In C89 it's undefined, but that's the exception to the rule, not the general case as you imply by "100% necessary". C++98 and C99 are not new, time to update your knowledge ;-)

Comment: @JonathanWakely Maybe you meant that comment as helpful, but I took it the polar opposite. So let me address as calmly as I can muster. One, I mentioned your own code must return if you tell the compiler to expect it. Two, it *should* warn you. Just because the standard automatically fixes your mistakes because of a wrapper around `main` doesn't mean you should make them. Three, I use C++17 in clang. Four, I have literally encountered this as a bug in low level code. C/C++ can be used without the standard library and without an operating system. Take your "learn it again" attitude elsewhere.

Comment: It's not a mistake though. The standard guarantees the behaviour, relying on that is not a mistake. You said "100% necessary" and that's just **wrong**.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

One way is to signal an interrupt:

```
#include <csignal>

// Generate an interrupt
std::raise(SIGINT);
```

In C:

```
#include <signal.h>
raise(SIGINT);
```

**UPDATE**: [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/signal) says that Windows doesn't really support `SIGINT`, so if portability is a concern, you're probably better off using `SIGABRT`.

> SIGINT is not supported for any Win32 application. When a CTRL+C interrupt occurs, Win32 operating systems generate a new thread to specifically handle that interrupt. This can cause a single-thread application, such as one in UNIX, to become multithreaded and cause unexpected behavior.

Comment: Yes, this should work across operating systems/compilers/debuggers.

Comment: I don't know other debuggers, but gdb is pretty flexible about [signal handling](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_39.html).

Comment: @Jefromi Most decent debuggers have knobs and switches that allow you to control how they handle various signals.

Comment: We found SIGTRAP better on some Unices

Comment: in Windows, MSVC you can use __debug_break, DebugBreak or _asm {int 3}.

Comment: @FernandoGonzalezSanchez: actually the function name is `__debugbreak()` and *NOT* `__debug_break()`, as you can see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/f408b4et.aspx)

Answer (score 46):

Disappointing to see so many answers not using the dedicated signal for software breakpoints, `SIGTRAP`:

```c
#include <signal.h>

raise(SIGTRAP); // At the location of the BP.
```

On MSVC/MinGW, you should use `DebugBreak`, or the `__debugbreak` intrinsic. A simple `#ifdef` can handle both cases (POSIX and Win32).

Comment: Some platforms (e.g. Msys2), do not have `SIGTRAP` defined.

Comment: For whatever reason, my debugger didn't always respect the signal, but if I issued it twice in row (like `raise(SIGTRAP); raise(SIGTRAP);`) , that seemed to work reliably!

Answer (score 32):

By looking [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130605011618/http://www.technochakra.com:80/software-breakpoints/), I found the following way:

```
void main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    asm("int $3");
    int a = 3;
    a++;  //  In gdb> print a;  expect result to be 3
}
```

This seems a touch hackish to me.  And I think this only works on x86 architecture.

Comment: And only with compilers supporting the AT&T assembly syntax. In particular, Microsoft's compiler (`cl.exe`) does not support this syntax, but uses a different syntax.

Comment: the question was about linux, so i guess we can assume that the gcc syntax will work for x86.

Comment: BTW - I did try the above on my x86 machine and it did work.  I was curious if there was a better way of doing it.  Looks like there is.

Comment: I am using mingw on windows so the other suggestions can't help me. Raising SIGINT signal just terminates the application, SIGTRAP is not defined in mingw headers... Using int instruction actually sends SIGTRAP and gdb breaks nicely on the appropriate line.

Comment: In Linux, `int 3` raises a SIGTRAP.

Comment: Nice and spooky. I like it.

Answer (score 29):

In a project I work on, we do this:

```
raise(SIGABRT);  /* To continue from here in GDB: "signal 0". */
```

(In our case we wanted to crash hard if this happened outside the debugger, generating a crash report if possible. That's one reason we used SIGABRT. Doing this portably across Windows, Mac, and Linux took several attempts. We ended up with a few #ifdefs, helpfully commented here: http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/98fa9c0cff7a/js/src/jsutil.cpp#l66 .)

Comment: As usual windows does not look like the others :)

Comment: Is it possible to issue "signal 0" to continue program the program in a paused state?  It would be nice to be able to use 'n' or 's' from this point, without a 'c' being issued.

Comment: @JasonDoucette If you really just want the program to pause, you might want to add a `breakpoint()` function in your program (it can be empty or just contain a print statement) and add `break breakpoint` to your `~/.gdbinit`.

Answer (score 13):

`__asm__("int $3");` should work:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    /* set breakpoint here! */
    int a = 3;
    __asm__("int $3");
    a++;  /*  In gdb> print a;  expect result to be 3 */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I like to `#define` this, so that I don't have toi remember the syntax. I have it sprinkled throughout my code, sometimes in place of `assert()`, since stopping the debiugger let's me examine all variables & the stack. And, of course, like assert, I don't have to remove it for production code

Comment: Interesting that this has 10 upvotes when the question constraints of "Linux" and "GDB" give plenty of options outside of resorting to assembly, which should always be a last resort for portability's sake if nothing else. Please see some of the other answers.

Comment: @BenjaminCrawfordCtrl-Alt-Tut In this specific case conceptually raising a SIGTRAP signal is a good idea. Of course the answer could be improved by specifying to do `raise()` instead, but it is valuable to see what goes behind it.

Comment: @Ralph `int $3` is only "what goes behind it" on x86 systems, which the question doesn't specify...

Answer (score 0):

On OS X you can just call `std::abort()` (it might be the same on Linux)

Comment: Which library ?

Comment: This is part of the standard C++ library and is cross-platform where C++11-compliant compilers exist. This however, raises SIGABRT, which is not really an appropriate signal to raise in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

[`<debugging>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/debugging) will be available in C++26: `std::breakpoint`, `std::breakpoint_if_debugging` and `std::is_debugger_present`.

The cppreference documentations for `std::breakpoint` and `std::is_debugger_present` also mention some of the current solutions.