# How to set a breakpoint programmatically in Fortran / Raise a SIGINT in Fortran

Tags: fortran, gdb, signals, sigint, raise

I want the debugger (Gdb) attached to my Fortran program to stop under some programmed circumstances.
In C/C++ this is easily possible:  [Set breakpoint in C or C++ code programmatically for gdb on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326414/set-breakpoint-in-c-or-c-code-programmatically-for-gdb-on-linux)

How to raise such a signal in Fortran?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call the same C system function as in the linked answer

```
  use iso_c_binding, only: c_int
  
  implicit none

  interface
    function raise(sig) bind(C, name="raise")
      use iso_c_binding, only: c_int
      integer(c_int) :: raise
      integer(c_int), value :: sig
    end function
  end interface

  integer(c_int), parameter :: SIGINT = 2
  
  
  print *, raise(SIGINT)
    
end
```

It is probably not easy to avoid entering the SIGINT integer value manually. Consult your `signal.h` or `man raise`. The value 2 is for POSIX. On POSIX systems you can also use `SIGTRAP = 5`.

Comment: If OP is using gfortran, it provides `SIGNAL` as a function or subroutine as vendor extension.  Check the gfortran manual for details.

Comment: If I understand the manual correctly `SIGNAL` can only be used to set a signal handler! (see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/SIGNAL.html)