# gdb input redirection using cygwin

Tags: gdb, cygwin

It seems that input redirection in gdb does not work in Cygwin e.g

```
(gdb) run < input.txt
```

Is there other way to redirect input in gdb of Cygwin??

Comment: This is a limitation of Cygwin, there is various workarounds for that, you can try solutions of this related question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544325/input-redirection-in-gdb-mingw

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible when running gdb in cygwin. The [bug](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/1999-04/msg00308.html) exists for a quote long time, but apparently it's a hard one to fix - and probably the gdb devs prefer spending time on features/issues relevant to more common environments (such as Linux).

There are various possible workarounds; I'd prefer the first one since it's the cleanest and also useful while not debugging / running on cygwin:

- Add a command line argument, e.g. `-f whatever` with `whatever` being the filename to read from. If the argument is not present or set to `-`, read from stdin. The `-f -` option is optional of course but for arguments accepting filenames it's a common standard (as long as it makes sense) to handle `-` as "use stdin/out".
- Use the gdb hack mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3652530/298479) to remap stdin to a manually opened file inside the application:

  ```
  > gdb yourexecutable
  (gdb) break main
  (gdb) run
  (gdb) call dup2(open("input.txt", 0), 0)
  (gdb) continue
  ```

  This sets a breakpoint on the `main` function, then executes the program which will break right after entering `main`. Then [`dup2`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2) is used to replace the stdin fd (`0`) with a file descriptor of the input file.

Comment: Alas, this results in `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` with "GNU gdb (GDB) (Cygwin 8.1.1-1) 8.1.1" :(