# GDB Windows output redirection

Tags: windows, gdb, mingw

I have been attempting to follow the suggestions given in option 3 of the first answer to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544325/input-redirection-in-gdb-mingw). I have succeeded in using the provided commands to redirect input, but I can't manage to redirect output. Here's my commands:

```
# gdb debugee.exe
(gdb) b main
(gdb) run
(gdb) p dup2(open("output.txt", 256), 1) 
(gdb) c
```

Noticed that I am using 256 to say "create if not exist" and 1 instead of 0 to redirect stdout instead of stdin.

The file is created, and the program output appears to go *somewhere*, since it doesn't appear in the terminal window; but the file remains empty.

What am I doing wrong? Or are there additional considerations for output?

Answer (score 1):

You should first try:

```
p open("output.txt", 256)
```

and verify that this returns something other than `-1`.

The `O_CREAT` version of `open` actually takes 3 arguments. Assuming `O_CREAT` is in fact 256 on your system, and O_WRONLY is 1, the correct call should be something like

```
p open("output.txt", 257, 0744)
```

> What am I doing wrong?

Besides supplying garbage for the mode of newly-created file, you are creating it in read-only mode. The subsequent writes all fail because of that, and go *nowhere*.